How to externally invoke and automate the calculation of ABAQUS cae
As a CAE noob, I would like to ask if abqpy 2024 can externally call Abaqus cae to perform calculations?
The way I did it before: use the .rpy file of Abaqus cae to modify the code and modify it on pycharm, but the final runtime stage is still done in abaqus cae, which causes a lot of trouble: 1. you can't call abaqus directly externally. 2. you need to re-modify the code every time.
So I would like to ask: is it possible to call abaqus cae directly externally?

Yes and No. 
If you have Abaqus installed in your machine, and you want to use some Abaqus/Viewer commands, then YES (3rd option below). 
If you don't have Abaqus installed in your machine, then No.
There are multiple ways you can invoke Abaqus and run scripts.
abaqus cae script=<script name> --> You can run scripts with any Abaqus API commands i.e., cae and viewer. This requires Abaqus license.
abaqus viewer script=<script name> --> You can run scripts with ONLY Abaqus viewer API commands. This also requires Abaqus license.
abaqus python <script name> --> You can run scripts with ONLY Abaqus viewer API commands with some limitations such as you cannot use GUI related commands, can work with only 1 ODB at a time and so on... This does not require Abaqus license.
For more info, check out Abaqus Doc.
